# razor pages core local methods

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Is it OK to call a method in the @functions{} section in razor pages directly from HTML? This seems to work fine and it's much easier than calling an API, but I was wondering if there is a downside to this (security, performance, etc)?

For example, in the code...

```
@functions {

public class Tickets: PageModel
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _db { get; set; }
    public Tickets(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public string GetTickets(int Top) //--> THIS IS THE METHOD I AM CALLING
    {
        var data = _db.Tickets.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt).Take(Top);
        var jdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToList());
        return jdata;
    }
}
}
```

And the HTML...

```
<div class="card alert-warning" v-for="ticket in tickets">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{ticket.TicketSubject}}</h4>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            dismissSecs: 5,
            dismissCountDown: 5,
            tickets: @Html.Raw(Model.GetTickets(100)),  //-->THIS WORKS, BUT IT IS OK TO USE LIKE THIS?
            xx: ''
        }
 })
 </script>

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works because I believe the method is called when the page is being rendered and you have constant value being passed in. It would not automatically do something like update client-side without AJAX code being involved.

But to answer you question I think the 'more correct' approach is to set a binding property in the OnGet and reference that client-side

```
public class Tickets : PageModel
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _db { get; set; }
    public Tickets(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public string TicketData { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        TicketData = GetTickets(100);
    }

    public string GetTickets(int Top) 
    {
        var data = _db.Tickets.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedAt).Take(Top);
        var jdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.ToList());
        return jdata;
    }
}
```